# How can I change the space of "\t"?

Tags: java

So I want to print something using System.out.print(); and I want multiple entries to be separated by a certain distance, beginning at the same location. Is there a way to do what "\t" does but instead of a tab, I want it to be 3 spaces? like can I change how much space "\t" creates?

Comment: It's dictated by the console/terminal that `System.out.print()` is writing to. UNIX-like systems, for example, have the `tabs` command to set the terminal's tab width. If you want it to be controlled by Java, just write x spaces instead of a tab or implement your own tabulation logic.

Comment: `System.out.println(myString.replace("\t", "   "));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system.out.printf("Here are 3 spaces%3s. Did you see them?","");
```

The width specifier specifies a minimum of 3 characters to be printed, which defaults to whitespace for a string.